# Navigator.geolocation error (Provider gps is temporarily unavailable) when enable the GPS first time in React native Android

Tags: react-native

So whenever i clear and wipe the data from emulator and install my app and toggle the GPS switch for the first time, i get a dialog for help to improve the accuracy and after i agree **Provider gps is temporarily unavailable**  error starts coming.

```
navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(
       (position)=>{},
        (error)=>{       
          console.log(error)//Provider gps is temporary unavailable
         },
        {enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 2000} 
)
```

the error persists after then even when i close and open my app.

It only goes away when i refresh the entire app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding this permission in your `Android Manifest`

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```